# Weird error with NoClassDefFoundError in com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.aq.a

Tags: java, android

I have got a weird crash report on my google console which seems to be related with google ad module.
Here is a stack trace reported on Google Console.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at jp.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799081@14.7.99 (100400-223214910):3)
  at jo.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799081@14.7.99 (100400-223214910):3)
  at jq.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799081@14.7.99 (100400-223214910):19)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.aq.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799081@14.7.99 (100400-223214910):15)
  at iu.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799081@14.7.99 (100400-223214910):19)
  at iu.run (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799081@14.7.99 (100400-223214910):8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at ad.loadClass (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@14799081@14.7.99 (100400-223214910):4)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

This exception seems to be happened only on Android 9 devices. And I don't have got any clue about why this could happen.

I just want to know if there has been any update related with this ad module as per android 9.

Comment: I get this problem too, android 9 user appear complaining, is it related to admob?

Comment: @SimonHo I'm using `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` in my project and it looks like related with the crash. Not sure anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your target API to 27, or:

> Specify requirement for Apache HTTP Legacy library

> If your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or above, you must include the following declaration within the  element of AndroidManifest.xml.
>
> ```
>   <uses-library
>       android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
>       android:required="false" />
> ```

Sources:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/K1HKru7RutY

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

Comment: If you include that in the manifest, how many users won't be able to download the app?